# material-ui: Cannot find module: './AccessAlarm'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app, yarnpkg

We have a project using @material-ui. It's built upon:

- create-react-app: 3.4
- node: 10.18.1
- yarn: 1.21.1
- @material-ui: 4.9.x

This problem is weird: i can `yarn start` and `yarn build` locally, the versions are exactly the same as server. However, after I push to server, it failed:

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ @material-ui/icons@4.9.1
info All dependencies
└─ @material-ui/icons@4.9.1
Done in 8.27s.
+ yarn run build:dev
yarn run v1.21.1
$ cp .env.sample .env && react-scripts build
The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
  - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@material-ui/icons/esm/index.js
Cannot find module: './AccessAlarm'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: yarn add ./AccessAlarm.
```

The building steps on server is:

```
node -v
rm yarn.lock
rm -rf build node_modules
yarn install
yarn add @material-ui/core   // I have tried to run with and w/o these two lines
yarn add @material-ui/icons
yarn run build:dev
```

Anyone has any ideas about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yarn cache clean` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was occuring locally and this is what fixed it:

```
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

Then

```
yarn link
```

Then

```
yarn upgrade @material-ui/core
```

Then

```
yarn upgrade @material-ui/icons
```

Then

```
npm start
```